# How to find first room having 2 days free slots between consecutive reservations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like that:

```
room_id      date_reservartion
101          October, 01 2016 
101          October, 03 2016 
102          October, 02 2016
102          October, 05 2016 
103          October, 01 2016
103          October, 02 2016 
103          October, 04 2016
104          October, 04 2016
```

I try find first room with free 2 days free in row.

In this situation answer is **room 102** because have reservation on 2-10-2016 and 5-10-2016, 3-10 and 4-10 is free.
Could you help me?

Link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc7039)

Comment: interesting title :-)

Comment: slogan leveraged trade :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing two of my approaches.

**Approach #1:**

```
SELECT
    a.room_id
FROM
    booking a
INNER JOIN booking b ON a.room_id = b.room_id
AND a.date_reservartion < b.date_reservartion
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (

      SELECT 
       *
      FROM booking c 
      WHERE c.room_id = a.room_id 
      AND c.date_reservartion BETWEEN 
                (a.date_reservartion + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
                (b.date_reservartion - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
AND DATEDIFF(b.date_reservartion,a.date_reservartion) = 3
ORDER BY a.date_reservartion
LIMIT 1
```

**Approach #2:**

Here's another way you can achieve this using `MySQL user defined variables`.

```
SELECT 
a.room_id
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(@prevRoom = room_id, @rn := @rn + 1,
         IF(@prevRoom := room_id, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
    ) AS rn
    FROM booking
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevRoom := 0, @rn := 1) AS var 
    ORDER BY room_id, date_reservartion
)AS a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(@prevRoom2 = room_id, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1,
         IF(@prevRoom2 := room_id, @rn2 := 1, @rn2 := 1)
    ) AS rn
    FROM booking
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevRoom2 := 0, @rn2 := 1) AS var 
    ORDER BY room_id, date_reservartion
) AS b

ON a.room_id = b.room_id AND a.rn = b.rn+1
WHERE DATEDIFF(a.date_reservartion,b.date_reservartion) = 3
```

---

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc7039/20/0)</kbd>

**Note:**

If you need only the first free room of that kind then add the following two lines in the above query:

```
ORDER BY a.date_reservartion 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
Select top 1 * from (
    Select a.room_id,DATEDIFF(DAY,a.date_reservartion,b.date_reservartion)-1 as Diff
    FROM room as a  
    INNER JOIN room as b on a.room_id=b.Room_id
) as t Where Diff = 2
Order by room_id
```

It is showing 102 see..

[image]

Comment: This will pick `room_id = 103` in the final result too.

Comment: I need only room_id=102

Comment: if you remove top 1 then it will show you all the rooms vacant for 2 days and as we have Order by it will show in proper order.

Comment: Yes, but i need 2 days free in row @Husen

Comment: Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 Select top 1 a.room_id,DATEDIFF(DAY,a.date_reservartion,b.date_reservartion)-1 as Diff
         FROM room as a  
            INNER JOIN room as b on a.room_id=b.room_id Where Diff = 2 Order by a.room_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Every room is free after 2016-10-05, here is an sql that shows when room is free for 2 days. You can easy modify it to see any free period (+ interval N day). If you apply **limit 1**, you will see the first free room.

```
select 
  room_id,
  date_reservartion + interval 1 day AS from_date,
  date_reservartion + interval 2 day AS to_date
from booking as b
where not exists (
    select 1
    from booking as b2
    where b2.room_id = b.room_id
    and b2.date_reservartion >= b.date_reservartion + interval 1 day
    and b2.date_reservartion <= b.date_reservartion + interval 2 day
)

order by from_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
SELECT top 1 room_id
  FROM (SELECT a.*, (b.date_reservartion - a.date_reservartion - 1) diff
          FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY room_id) rn, room_id,
                       date_reservartion
                  FROM booking) a inner join
               (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY room_id) rn, room_id,
                       date_reservartion
                  FROM booking) b
         On a.room_id = b.room_id AND a.rn = b.rn - 1) t
 WHERE diff = 2
```

It is Showing 102